# Box Decoration Break Clone With Padding And Text Centered Doesn't work Correctly on iOS

Tags: css, ios

I have a parent container with `text-align: center;` with a span inside with `-webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;` and `padding: 0 10px;`.

On iOS the span overflows on the right side of the parent container. I see that when I remove the `padding` from the span, it doesn't overflow and works properly.

But the padding in the span works properly on any other device.

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
}

span {
  box-decoration-break: clone;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Est eveniet, porro eius odio doloremque assumenda similique eaque saepe quae voluptatibus quod, ratione temporibus qui, fugit repellat incidunt veritatis. Sapiente, ducimus?
  </span>
</div>
```

### Here is a screenshot of an iPhone without the padding in the span:

[image]

### And here is a screenshot of an iPhone with the padding in the span and it overflowing:

[image]